# Jquery Select2 Ajax+Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

```js
$("#nomlabo").select2({
    //tags:true,
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "includes/labotags.php",
        results: function (data) {
            //alert(data[1]);
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
    },
    tags: ["result1", "result2", "result3", "result4"],
    maximumSelectionSize: 1
});
```

> hi i want to put the values from Data results into the "tags",
>   how could this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have changed the code to get from php instead jquery :

```
$("#nomlabo").select2({
            tags: [
            <?php
            $results =array();
                if ($stm = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM laboratoire")) {
                        $stm->execute();
                        $stm->store_result();
                        $stm->bind_result($id,$nom_labo,$id_nationalite);
                        while ($stm->fetch()) {
                            echo '"'.$nom_labo.'",';
                        }
                    }
            ?>
            ],
            maximumSelectionSize: 1
        });
```